# How can I know which order for the paypal payment?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, payment

This is my paypal program, first I create an order and get the order id

Then create the payment to paypal

When user finish the payment, how can I know that payment is for which order at `ExecutePayment`?

```
//create customer's order and get the order id
$orderId=insertToDatabase();

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
    ->setPrice(7.5);
$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName('Granola bars')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(5)
    ->setSku("321321") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
    ->setPrice(2);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));


$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping(1.2)
    ->setTax(1.3)
    ->setSubtotal(17.50);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD")
    ->setTotal(20)
    ->setDetails($details);


$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription("Payment description")
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());


$baseUrl = 'http://site/paypal';
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment?success=true")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment?success=false");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));


try {
    $apiContext = getApiContext('11111', '2222');
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
    exit(1);
}

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

 echo "Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.";
 echo "<a href='$approvalUrl' >$approvalUrl</a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the order variable in your return URL

```
$baseUrl = 'http://site/paypal';
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment?success=true&orderid=1")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment?success=false&orderid=1");
```

Comment: If I just simply pass the id in url, how to know the payment is really complete? user may guess order id and go to ExecutePayment?success=true&orderid=1 to complete the order in my system

Comment: You can extend the sample I provided to implement it in any manner, such as a GUID that represents your order.

Comment: I just tried to use GUID as order id, but it is still not safe. I click cancel at paypal login, then it redirect to `ExecutePayment?success=false&orderguid=xxxxxx`, I must pass the id to handle the order at false case. Even the user cannot guess the order id, this program is still not safe.